# Portrait Orientation on Android Smart TV

Tags: android, google-tv

I had used following code to show my screen in Portrait mode.

> View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

root.getLayoutParams().height = width;
root.getLayoutParams().width = height;
root.requestLayout();

root.setPivotX(height);
root.setPivotY(height);

Animator anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.anim.rotate_90);      
anim.setTarget(root);
anim.start();
```

My root view contain VideoView. After Screen rotation videoview played, but it doesn't show video frames, it plays only the audio of the video source only. And I need to show the mouse cursor on portrait mode.  How to handle this?

Note:

**I had tried to implement Portrait orientation to my Smart TV application.As per developer site their is no possibility to implement Portrait on Google TV. 
Refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_market_filtering)**

Comment: Can you post your UI. There might be the problem.

Comment: Link is not working now